# Create Onject/Array dynamic

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, razor

Hello and thanks for reading this.

I have the code below:

```
public JsonResult Events()
    {
        List<Raid> raids = db.Raids.ToList();

        foreach (var item in raids)
        {

        }

        var rows = new object[] { 
            new { title="Event1", start= "2015-07-04" }, 
            new { title="Event2", start= "2015-07-05" } 
        };

        return Json(rows, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

I would like the part below to be dynamic/Create by the foreach loop.

```
var rows = new object[] { 
            new { title="Event1", start= "2015-07-04" }, 
            new { title="Event2", start= "2015-07-05" } 
        };
```

Can someone tell me how I can do that or any other way of doing it. Kinda running low on ideas about how to solve it.

It is used to my Calendar :

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        defaultDate: output, //'2015-02-12',
        editable: false,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        events: '@Url.Content("~/Members/Events")'
    });
```

Comment: Are you asking how to iterate through List<Raid> raids to generate an array of rows?

Comment: shouldn't you be using array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, Im sure this will solve your problem

```
public class callender{
        public string title;
        public DateTime start;
    }

    public JsonResult Events()
    {
        List<Raid> raids = db.Raids.ToList();

        List<callender> cal = new List<callender>();

        foreach (var item in raids)
        {
            cal.Add(new callender { title = item.Instance, start = item.Date });
        }

        return Json(cal, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```